# The difference between "the battery charge time" and "the battery charging time"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the phrases below?

*The battery charging time*

*The battery charge time*

Comment: **If** they mean anything different, the second one could possibly mean the usable battery time, when charged.

Answer (score 2):

They can mean the same thing: *the time taken to charge the battery*. The first is a little more natural.

As Weather Vane said, the second could also mean *the time provided by a battery charge*.